# How to get all the file's name from asset folder?

Tags: java, android

I have copied some folders to the assets folder. I have many folders inside the assets folder. I want to read all the folders name.

What I am doing is

```
tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String path = "file:///android_asset/";

        Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
        File directory = new File(path);
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
        }

    }
});
```

But the error it is showing is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
  at com.example.ashura.browsetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
```

Comment: That code will not do. You cannot use the File class as they are no files in assets. Google for assets manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read all the folders name.

Call `getAssets()` on a `Context` to get an `AssetManager`. Call `list()` on it to retrieve the contents of your assets.

> What I am doing is

`file:///android_asset/` works for `WebView` and little else. It does not work with `File`.